# How to add a series of string in incrementing id in any table?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have MySQL Table with an Order table in a DB this table has an auto-incremental id. Up-till now we have general numeric Order-ID likewise 1,2,3,4,5... From now onwards I have to append the series A20 to my id like A20103, A20104, A20105 and so on and when the last three digits reaches 999 the series appended should get changed to A21001, A21002, A21003 and so on, the same series has to be added in the previously added orders..

How can i achieve this task? please guide

Comment: Is your primary key a separate column from your order id column? You cannot have an alpha-numeric `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. Also, your example is not clear. Do you just want to prefix `A2` to your order id, so that order id 1 becomes `A20001`, order id 999 becomes `A20999` and order id 1000 becomes `A21000`?

Comment: Yes primary key is same orderid, and I need to append A20 to my ids like A20001 for id=1, A20002 for id=2 an so on and when i reach id = 999 it should be A20999 and next id should become A21001

Comment: Why does it need to jump from A20999 to A21001? Is there a reason for missing out A21000?

Comment: Point to be Noted  :) I will ask this to him, what about main requirement

Comment: @OM The Eternity: The majority of answers are suggesting the same thing: leave the ID column alone, and just format the output as necessary. This can be done using a suitable `SELECT` query, as suggested by Kieran Allen and me, or do it from PHP, as suggested by Jim. Unless you have a *really really* good reason to change the primary key, leave it alone! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along the lines of:

```
"AR2" . str_pad((int) $ordernumber, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

jim

**[edit]** - i'm assuming this is for display purposes as stated elsewhere, the ID field on the DB is integer!!

Comment: Yes Its true just to get a proper alphanumeric orderid

Comment: MO - in that case, you'd prolly want to do the 'padding' in sql. maybe similar to this: concat('A', LPAD(orderid, 5, '0'))

Answer (score 4):

Altering an existing auto_increment column does not sound like a good idea - do you really have to do this?  Instead, why not just modify your select query to return a suitably formatted id?  By doing so, you maintain referential integrity, and you are also free to change the order id format at any time in the future, without having to update your database.

```
SELECT id, CONCAT('A2', LPAD(id, 4, '0')) AS order_id FROM <table>;
```

Example output:

```
+------+----------+
| id   | order_id |
+------+----------+
|    1 | A20001   |
|    2 | A20002   
...
|  999 | A20999   |
| 1000 | A21000   |
| 1001 | A21001   |
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an auto-increment which is not a numeric field. You will better keep the current auto-incrementing column, and add a new one which you will compute manually according to your rules.

You'll probably want to use the MAX() function to get the latest order and generate the next value: remember to do it within a transaction.

You could create a function or a trigger, to do the insert cleanly for you.

Comment: +1 my Client has asked me to change the order id into this format as order id is used everywhere, and to have a proper alphanumeric format he needs it in this way...

Answer (score 0):

You can't add prefixes directly to the database. However, when selecting it you can prepend it.

```
SELECT concat('A', id) as id FROM table
```

To get the effect of starting from 20000 you can set the auto increment starting value.