# create a PK column combining letters and numbers

Tags: mysql, vb6, auto-increment

I have a product purchasing system and I want to have a unique identifier with the format PID*n*, where *n* is an autoincrementing number.

- PID00001
- PID00002
- PID00003

How can this be done with VB6 and MySQL?

Comment: could you ask what you need specifically?

Comment: I want a code to achieve this. I've searched about COncAT but i don't know how to use this.

Comment: Since a PK should never be exposed by any UI anyway why would you care whether they are integer values, GUIDs, or anything else?

Comment: You don't want the code to achieve this. If you do want it, you're using a relational database in entirely wrong way and you require reading up on what primary keys are, what they do and especially how they help MySQL maintain performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You can either prefix and pad your auto-increment integer or have two separate columns that are combined by a trigger. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245530/679449) for a better explanation.